# EJB 3.1 Message-driven beans bindings in Websphere 8 using Listener ports

Tags: jakarta-ee, message-driven-bean, websphere-8

Does anybody know how to configure the EJB 3.1 deployment descriptor in Websphere 8 and the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file for a message-driven bean that uses a listener port instead of an activation specification? The IBM info center is quite vague on this matter and I'm having trouble knowing exactly what to put in both the ejb-jar.xml and ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml files.

Thanks,
Rida

Answer (score 1):

The ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml snippet would look like this:

```
<ejb-jar-bnd ...>
  <message-driven name="MDBean">
    <listener-port name="TestLP"/>
  </message-driven>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

However, per the [AdminApp documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html), this does not work unless a special option is passed to wsadmin:

> To use the existing listener port instead of using or creating a new
>   activation specification, determine whether the EJB JAR version is
>   lower than 2.1. The system automatically creates and uses an
>   activation specification when you specify the -usedefaultbindings
>   option to deploy an application. If an activation specification
>   exists, the system ignores the listener port, and instead uses the
>   activation specification. To deploy an application with an EJB JAR
>   version greater than or equal to 2.1 using the defined listener ports
>   instead of a new activation specification, set the
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.application.dfltbndng.mdb.preferexisting
>   system property to true in the wsadmin.properties file in the
>   properties directory of the profile of interest.